# missing TLS protocol in wireshark preferences

Tags: wireshark

I've installed `wireshark` on `Centos 7.9.2009` however I don't find TLS on the protocols list in preferences settings.

Is it something missing to be installed yet or the wireshark version available on Centos repository is old/obsolete?

I also tried with `wireshark 2.6.6` from another [wireshark repo](https://www.1310nm.net/repository/CentOS/7/wireshark.repo) but the TLS protocol under preferences is missing also

What I have installed now is:

```
wireshark-gtk-2.6.6-1.x86_64
wireshark-qt-2.6.6-1.x86_64
wireshark-2.6.6-1.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find it in the protocols list as "SSL".

TLS was developed from SSL, and until SSL was shown to have fatal vulnerabilities and completely deprecated, both were often handled together as SSL/TLS.

Wireshark initially listed SSL/TLS as just "SSL" (probably because TLS did not yet exist back then), and since it still maintains the capability to also analyze SSL, has not changed the name in the protocol settings menu yet.